# Ruby - if else statement

Tags: ruby, if-statement, expression

I have been working on the configuration an `else` statement.
Here is the code:

```
puts "Do you like PC?"
case (gets.chomp)
when 'yes'
  puts "I do too"
when 'no'
  puts "Mac is better"
end
```

Now I am trying to configure it to (1) use `else`, and (2) to use `elsif`. How do I better write this to use "else", and how do I write it to use `elsif`. Here is what I wrote for the `else` version

```
puts "Do you like PC?"
case (gets.chomp)
if 'yes'
  puts "I do too"
else
  puts "Mac is better"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should re-write as:

```
puts "Do you like PC?"
answer = gets.chomp

if answer == 'yes'
  puts "I do too"
elsif answer == 'maybe'
  puts "you're confused"
else
  puts "Mac is better"
end
```

The keyword `case` is preserved for case statements.

Comment: Thank you Sagarpandy. How would you write it using ELSIF?

Comment: OH... cool. Thank you. That was on time, you rock @sagarpandya82!